# Inkscape 9.2 not drawing circles or ovals with Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: inkscape, shapes

I am using Inkscape 0.92 on Ubuntu 18.04.  When I try to draw a circle or an oval the object draws as shown below.
This is not a color, transparancy, or draw order issue.  Do I need to reinstall Inkscape to an earlier version?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the Tool Controls Bar along the top, for the Ellipse Tool.

Hit the "Whole Ellipse" button shown highlighted in red here

[image]

Also make sure the Ellipse has a coloured fill (not white) or a stroke (not white) applied, otherwise it will be invisible!  You can change the fill or stroke in the *Fill and Stroke Panel* (Shift+Ctrl+F).

Note that 0.92 is old, although that isn't the source of your problem.  The most recent version of Inkscape to date is 1.0.1

Comment: Thanks @Billy Kerr, that was the fix.  I appreciate your help and have accepted your answer.  I did upgrade to 1.0.1 and had the same issue but again, your answer solved my problem.

Answer (score -1):

I haven’t encountered this issue while using Inkscape or seen it before. I believe that updating to Inkscape 1.0 may work.
Hope this helps!